# Question on proof of upper bound for number of maximal cliques in an $N_{t+1}$-free graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

I have a question on the beginning of the proof of the main theorem in

> M. Farber, M. Hujter, and Z. Tuza, “An upper bound on the number of cliques in a graph,” Networks, vol. 23, no. 3, pp. 207–210, 1993, doi: 10.1002/net.3230230308.

The theorem is

> Theorem. Let $\mathbf{t}$ be a natural number, and let $\mathbf{G}$ be an $\mathbf{N}_{t+1}$-free graph on $n \geq 4 t$ vertices. Then
> $$
> \boldsymbol{\kappa}(\mathbf{G})<\sqrt[3]{t} e^{1-t}\left(\begin{array}{c}
> n \\
> 2 t
> \end{array}\right),
> $$

where $N_t$ is the graph obtained by deleting a perfect matching from the complete graph on $2t$ vertices (sometimes called the [cocktail party graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CocktailPartyGraph.html)), and $\kappa(G)$ is the number of maximal cliques of $G$.

The beginning of the proof goes

**2. PROOF OF THE THEOREM**

Let $$ f(n, t)=\sqrt[3]{t} e^{1-t}\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ 2 t \end{array}\right) . $$

First we prove the theorem for $n=4 t$. The case $t=1$ is trivial: one can see that a 4-vertex graph can contain at most 4 cliques, and, on the other hand, $f(4,1)=6$. For $t \geq 2$, applying the theorem of Moon and Moser [8], it suffices to show that $f(4 t, t)>3^{4t / 3}$. This inequality can easily be checked by induction on $t$. Therefore, in the rest of the proof we assume that $n \geq 4 t+1$. We prove the theorem by induction on $t+n$. (The proof is already done for $t+n=5$.)

Given a graph $\mathbf{G}=(V,E)$, let $v \in V$ be any fixed vertex. Set $W=\{w \in V \backslash\{v\} \mid v w \notin E\}$ and $s=|W|$. Denote by $\mathbf{G}-v$ the subgraph induced by $V \backslash\{v\}$, and put $m=f(n, t)-f(n-1, t)$. Furthermore, let $\mu$ denote the largest integer satisfying the following condition: There exist distinct cliques $C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_\mu$ in $\mathbf{G}$ such that no set $C_j^{\prime \prime}=C_j \backslash\{v\}$ is a clique in $G-v$.

Observe that $\boldsymbol{\kappa}(\mathbf{G})-\boldsymbol{\kappa}(\mathbf{G}-v) \leq \mu$. **Since the distinct sets $C_j^{\prime \prime}$ induce complete subgraphs, there exist cliques $C_j^{\prime \prime} \supseteq C_j^{\prime \prime}$ in $\mathbf{G}-v$, and clearly, $\emptyset \neq C_j^{\prime} \backslash C_j \subseteq W$ for $j=1,2, \ldots, \mu$.** For a vertex $w \in W$, let $r$ denote the number of those indices $j$ for which $w \in C_j^{\prime} \backslash C_j$ holds. Let us fix a vertex $w \in W$ such that $r$ is maximum. Then $\mu \leq r s$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $w \in C_j^{\prime} \backslash C_j$ for $j=1,2, \ldots, r$. By the induction hypothesis, $\mathbf{G}-v$ has fewer than $f(n-1, t)$ cliques. (Here $\mathbf{G}-v$ has at least $4 t$ vertices, by assumption.) Therefore, it suffices to show that $\mu \leq m$ which, by $\mu \leq r s$, reduces to $r s \leq m$. We will prove this inequality.

#### Question

I can follow the idea of the proof, I think, but I'm rather confused by these sets $C_j, C_j^{\prime \prime}$, and $C_j^\prime$. In particular, I don't follow this sentence above in **bold.** The relation $C_j^{\prime \prime} \supseteq C_j^{\prime \prime}$ is a tautology, so I assume it's a typo, but I can't work out what the right statement is. **How are these $C_j, C_j^\prime, C_j^{\prime \prime}$ operating within the proof?**